# Accessing Beaglebone python opencv usb camera but the display showing black screen

Tags: python, opencv, video, usb, webcam-capture

I am facing issue while accessing USB camera using beagle-bone black wireless.
Firstly the error is "select timeout" exception which was resolved by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208580/opencv-3-2-gives-select-timeout-when-grabbing-but-fswebcam-works/43230529#43230529)

Now I am facing the black screen in output.

Here is the testing code I am using.

```
from cv2 import *
# initialize the camera
cam = VideoCapture(0)   # 0 -> index of camera
print "Cam capture"
cam.set(3,320)
cam.set(4,240)
print "Cam set"
s, img = cam.read()
print "Cam read"
if s:    # frame captured without any errors
    namedWindow("cam-test",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    imshow("cam-test",img)
    while True:
        key = waitKey(30)
        if key == ord('q') :
                destroyWindow("cam-test")
```

I have already check that video0 in /dev directory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to call 'cam.read()`and`imshow()` **inside the while loop**

What you're doing is that you're reading just the first frame, then showing it, and you `while`loop isn't doing anything. When the camera boots, the first frame is just a blank screen , which is what you see.

The code should be more like:

```
    while True:
        s, img = cam.read()
        imshow("cam-test",img)
        key = waitKey(30)
        if key == ord('q') :
                destroyWindow("cam-test")
```